# Export Multiple Contacts from Shared Activity Task in salesforce

Tags: tasks, activities

we have "Shared Activities" enabled on Tasks, which allows adding multiple contacts to the "Name" field on a Task object.

**Question**: does anyone know how to export all contacts that are entered in Name field on Task? 
Currently, I can only extract one contact Id from that field (API Name: WhoId) using reports or data loader.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`TaskWhoRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_taskwhorelation.htm) sObject, which is a read-only, filtered version of [`TaskRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm). `TaskRelation` stores all Task relationships, including the `What` (Related To), while `TaskWhoRelation` includes records only for `Who` (Name), that is, for Leads and Contacts.

You can perform a subquery against this relationship, as shown in the linked documentation:

```
 SELECT Id, Subject, (SELECT RelationId, Relation.Name, Type from TaskWhoRelations) FROM Task
```

or you can query it directly:

```
SELECT RelationId, Relation.Name, Type, TaskId FROM TaskWhoRelation
```

Note that because `RelationId` is polymorphic, you won't be able to directly access most Contact or Lead fields through the relationship; you'd need to accumulate those Ids and perform a separate query against Contact or Lead.